# what does it mean that a system is attractive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, statistical-mechanics

What does it mean that a system is *attractive* in the context of Statistical Mechanics? Is this notion related to the presence of some monotonicity properties?

Comment: Some more context (perhaps usage of the word in a sentence) would be helpful. That said, in dynamical systems we have a notion of attractor, and in that setting an entire system would be attractive if all trajectories (for all initial conditions) are pulled towards some attractor. Something similar makes sense for the random dynamical systems that appear in statistical mechanics.

Comment: Basically, it means that the associated stochastic dynamics preserves monotonicity. Look at Liggett's book "Interacting Particle Systems".